# Getting strings from words in Rebol

Tags: types, foreach, cpu-word, rebol

I really feel like I'm missing something simple, so I apologize in advance for even having to ask. In Rebol how do you get a string value from a word/variable in a block? I have this code:

```
REBOL []
aLink: "http://google.com"
anAtt: "href"
aList: [anAtt aLink]
print "Test 1"
foreach el aList [ print type? el ]
print "Test 2"
foreach el2 aList [ print el2]
print "Test 3"
foreach el2 aList [ print string! el2]
```

That returns this:

```
Test 1
word
word
Test 2
anAtt
aLink
Test 3
string
string
```

What I'd like up in Test 2 is for it to return the values of aLink and anAtt, but in every combination it returns the word name. What am I doing wrong? I'm doing this in REBOL/Core 2.7.8.4.2 on 32-bit Ubuntu using the 2.3 libc binary.

I've used foreach and blocks in other Rebol programs before and never had this trouble. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Rebol how do you get a string value from a word/variable in a block?

If you have a WORD! in a value, and it is bound *(the ones you have here happen to be)* then you're looking for **get**.

```
a-link: http://google.com
an-att: "href"
a-list: [an-att a-link]
foreach el a-list [ print get el ]
```

Output should be:

```
href
http://google.com
```

Note modifications.  CamelCase-type stuff is not common in Rebol, being case-insensitive for lookup.  Also, if you don't strike the quotes from URL! and use the URL! datatype you're missing out on one of the niceties.  :-)

Also note that PRINT will implicitly REDUCE a block you give it.  So **print a-list** gives you:

```
href http://google.com
```

Comment: 1. Love the username. It make me smile, and I needed that today.

2. THANK YOU!!!

3. I'm actually working on a little webpage builder, so the string type is what I'm looking for, but yeah the URL type is awesome. Love when writing client programs. :)

Comment: @AndrewBurton Not to discourage the use of the Q&A which is the site's actual purpose *(it's preferable to format and ask questions as questions)* but [there is also a chat room here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red)